# Can libcURL be configured to use my .curlrc when used from PHP

Tags: php, drupal, curl, drush

I'm using [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and [Drush Make](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) to automate download of Drupal module from a corporate network behind a NTLM-SSPI Proxy. Drush and Drush Make uses cURL to download files. cURL supports NTLM-SSPI Proxy. I configured cURL for the proxy in my .curlrc file

```
--proxy proxy.example.com:8080
--proxy-ntlm
--proxy-user user:password
```

Drush itself is able to download modules from drupal.org because it uses `curl` from the command line. But Drush Make uses the [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php) API (libcurl) . It looks like when used this way, cURL does not use the configuration in my .curlrc file.

Is there a way to configure libcurl/PHP cURL with a .curlrc file ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the entire .curlrc parser and all associated logic is only present in the command line tool code. It is not included in the library at all. (and the PHP/CURL binding is only using libcurl the library, not the command line tool)

Answer (score -2):

drush really loads the command line tool and runs it, so you can do this in the ~/.curlrc file, but you need to make sure your commands are correctly setup.

```
leet@test:~$ cat ~/.curlrc
# Proxy manly for drush make
proxy = http://localhost:3128
# Drush make work around for https
#insecure
```

Can be made with ...

```
echo -e "\n# Proxy manly for drush make\nproxy = http://localhost:3128 \n /
#Drush make work around for https \n#insecure\n" >> ~/.curlrc
```

Remember, this will only work for your user, I think you can set a system wide default if you put curlrc in the same folder your bin file is in or /etc/curl, but I have not tested this.

I use this all the time, for quick aegir builds.
Hope that helps.
LeeT